# ERR_INVALID_CERT_AUTHORITY on Cloud-flare universal certificate ( google chrome suspected )

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, cloudflare

I am having this strange issue with SSL on my site. The domain is pointed towards Cloudflare and I am using flexible SSL settings. The universal default certificate is set on Cloudflare. 
Now all my devices ( android, ios, windows, and any browser Edge, Chrome, Safari ) it works perfectly. But some users are complaining that they get NET::ERR_INVALID_CERT_AUTHORITY.
I have tried it with a lot of versions of google chrome(56-77). And both developers on the team all tried plus for other people I know it works. But some users ( according to client 70%) face this issue. Even the client is not having this issue.

Website is : https://beinhaoranim.co.il or https://www.beinhaoranim.co.il

please don't duplicate or something like that. I have serched through whole web and my problem is unique. Other solutions are most related to google chrome and its same on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue long time ago which you can read in my post [ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID](https://www.empowerwebsite.com/ssl/cloudflare-ssl-error-showing-err_cert_authority_invalid/). I am explaining the same below.

1. The main reason is "SSL Certificate" conflict. What was happening is that
   there was already a SSL on the hosting and sometime the SSL is
   self-signed so make sure there is no other ssl certificate for that
   site as it will conflict with the SSL provided by CloudFlare.
2. Download the SSL provided by CloudFlare and install on the
       hosting. Remove any earlier SSL of that site first. Wait for upto 24
       hours so that new changes are reflected everywhere.

Comment: Okay. I can try that. 
But when we select flexible option in cloudflare it just encrypt from client to cloudflare and not to origin server. What do you say?

Comment: After adding the SSL to the host change the setting from flexible to Full (strict) . This will ensure  a secure connection between both the visitor and your Cloudflare domain and between Cloudflare and your origin web server.